# Restore all security groups of the TFS 2010 collections after applying the TFSConfig repair command

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We've lost our TFS and domain servers. TFS was configured to use domain accounts. We could resotre only the TFS Project Collection databases and thanks to the "TFSConfig repair" command, we finally attached them to a new TFS instance.

But all of the default security groups for repaired projects are lost (except the administrators). For example we don't have "Contributors" group anymore.

Now we want to restore these standard groups. Maybe it's possible to fix it by applying the default TFS "project proccess templates" on all existing projects and collections again.

Is there any way to address it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you lost the Domain server you have to follow the **Move User and Service Accounts** chapter of the "[Move Team Foundation Server from One Environment to Another](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404883.aspx)" procedure.

By the way, there's no such feature as reapplying a process template on an existing Team Project.

Have you tried to recreate at least one group that you lost? Only to know if that is working (maybe TFS will return an error because the group still exists in the database but it's not shown for whatever reason) ?

One last thing: check the TFS Scheduler Windows Service is running on the TFS Server and look for errors in the Windows Event Log.

Comment: The new TFS is up and we don't have any problem about administrators access, we just lost the security groups which I think we can make them manually but I wan't to check if we can do it automatically (just about the security groups). Then we can assign the users permissions one by one.

Comment: You changed the AD, right ? Do you have the new AD accounts of TFS Service account AND TFS Users (e.g. the developers) remap the old's AD ones ? For instance when you make a View History on the Source Control do you have the User correctly displayed? It's weird that you lost only the TFS Security Group, those things are supposed to be stored in the TPC database.

Comment: You are absolutely right. About the history we don't have the users correctly displayed. But now the only one important to us is the TFS Security Group. In other word we want a clean TFS with old projects and just a history from the lost domain users (displaying the names incorrectly is not important). All users will be reassigned again.

Comment: The thing is you can't expect the TFS Server to behave normally if you didn't remap the old user accounts (believe me). You have to follow the step 2 of "Move User and Service Accounts", use the "TFSConfig identities" command to remap old user and service accounts. Chances are your security group still exist but are not displayed because the accounts that are members don't exist. This is different for the Administrator group as TFS make sure this one always exists & working.

Comment: As I said we installed a new clean TFS and attached the exisiting collections DBs using the "TFSConfig repair" command (It attaches the collections to the new TFS). It seems that we have to restore over all the old TFS and use the "TFSConfig identities" as you said? Right?

Comment: Yes, because the "Existing Collections DBs" use the old AD, so you have to remap the accounts referenced there to the new AD if you want the TPC to work.